# Gson gson = new Gson().toJson(data) - incompatible types

Tags: java, json, gson

I've been following a tutorial on turning an array of objects into JSON but I've come across a few errors that I can't find a solution for.

**CODE**

Line 60 - 64

```
Gson gson = new Gson().toJson(data);
response.setContentType("application/json"); 
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
response.getWriter().write(gson);
```

**ERRORS**

Line 60

```
incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: com.google.gson.Gson
            Gson gson = new Gson().toJson(data);
```

Line 64

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method write(com.google.gson.Gson)
location: class java.io.PrintWriter
            response.getWriter().write(gson);
```

Does anyone know how to properly do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 4):

It certainly looks from your error messages that it should be

```
String gson = new Gson().toJson(data);
```

which seems to address both of those errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use

> toJson() – Convert Java object to JSON format
>
> fromJson() – Convert JSON into Java object

Exmaple:

```
Employee obj = new Employee(); // Your java object
...

Gson gson = new Gson();

// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(obj);

response.getWriter().write(json);
```